# ImageView not filling entire ListView Item

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom `ListView` and an `ImageView` that I'm trying to use as the background.  When I run the app the image doesn't fill the `listItem` completely - i.e the background of the `listview` is showing through, and the `imageView` isn't completely filling the item.  Any suggestions as to how I can get the `imageView` to fill the whole layout?

I have the `ImageView` android: `layout_height` and `layout_width` set to `fill_parent`, so I would think it should fill the parent - which I believe is the `listView` cell correct? The Layout itself = parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of making an imageview and trying to like...stretch it perhaps, just set the drawable as the background of the listview cell itself.

Comment: I have to use an ImageView because its a custom listview with different backgrounds depending on item position.  So I'm doing setImageResource(R.drawable.blahblahblah) for each position case :\

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.  Thanks for the reply :)